# How to implement hierarchy of resources in java for resteasy

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I am writing a java based REST API based on resteasy. I have following structure

Category has many groups;  group has many preferences

I have 3 resources 1. category 2. group 3. preference

I want to support these API endpoints

- `/categories/{cat_id}/groups/`  (returns all groups for the category)
- `/groups/{group_id}/preferences/`   (returns all prefs for the group)
- `/preferences/{preference_id}` (returns a pref identified by the id passed)
- `/preferences` (returns all prefs)

I have 3 resource classes one for each resource mentioned above

I am confused how to structure the methods and where they should go. Following are my specific questions

1. `/groups/{group_id}/preferences/`  Should the implementation go under `GroupsResourceImpl` class or `PreferenceResourceImpl` class
2. `PreferenceResourceImpl` class has the implementation for `/preferences` end point which returns all the global preferences.   So if `/groups/{groupid}/preferences` endpoint reside under `GroupResource` and call a method on the `PreferenceResource` (a method that takes in group id as an extra param) ??

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the implementation makes no difference, you can do it either way. You should group them the way that groups the code the most logical way to you.

I, personally, like to group resource implementation the way that groups similar code together. This can be achieved by grouping together the paths that require similar ways to extract from the infrastructure. For example, if all your data is in relational database, then all your `/*/preferences` queries would be basically `SELECT * FROM preferences WHERE ...different stuff...`. Therefore, it would be most logical to group them all by the table you are querying from. For example:

> GroupResource: `/categories/{cat_id}/groups/`

Because it would always query from table "groups": `SELECT * FROM groups WHERE parent_cat_id = {cat_id}`

> PreferenceResource: `/groups/{group_id}/preferences/`, `/preferences/{preference_id}`, `/preferences`.

Because it would always query from table "preferences": `SELECT * FROM preferences WHERE parent_group = {group_id}`, `... WHERE id = {preference_id}`, `SELECT * FROM preferences`

However, if your categories/groups/preferences reside in some kind of graph database - then to query `/groups/{group_id}/preferences` you would need to first find a group, and then get all the preferences from the inside and therefore, it would be more logical to group resources like this:

> CategoryResource: `/categories/{cat_id}/groups/`

Because it would start querying from "categories" graph: `categories.get(cat_id).getGroups()`

> GroupResource: `/groups/{group_id}/preferences/`

Because it would start querying from "groups" graph:  `groups.get(group_id).getPreferences()`

> PreferenceResource: , `/preferences/{preference_id}`, `/preferences`.

Because it would start querying from "preferences" graph:  `preferences.get(preference_id)` and `preferences.getAll()`